# Use excepcion window as popup removing the traceback in Odoo

Tags: exception, popup, report, odoo

In Odoo 8, I want to print a qweb report and, in the moment of printing, I want to check if some field is missing. If so, I want to indicate that to the user through a popup window, otherwise the report would be directly printed.

what I am doing now is, once the report is called, the .xml file calls a method from the object that will do these checks and then raise an exception informing the user about the missing fields, but I do not want the traceback to be displayed, just my relevant information.

Does anyone have a suggestion about the better way to achieve that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to reply myself. The user clicks on the "Print" button. The report is triggered and the web code is executed. The first thing this code does is performing a call to a method from the sale.order which checks if the fields are set. In case some of them are not set it raises an orm_except. So the user is informed and the flow is interrupted, so the report is not being generated.